# Two hash tables to store integers

Tags: java, hash

I'm trying to implement 2 parallel hashtables that work together, specifically I would like that: when I insert a new key x it tries to insert it in the table T1. If the position in T1 is free, insertion is performed. If the position in T1 is occupied by the key y then the pre-existing key y is replaced and this is inserted in the other table. If the position in T2 is occupied by a third key z, the key z is positioned in T1 and so on. The beauty is that if you find a loop, the size of the tabellesi increases by 1 and you start again by re-inserting all the elements in the new table. If N / M> = 1/2, the size of the table is doubled, by re-entering the N inserted elements.

Obviously I have already written the basic structure that I attach to the post.

I suppose that table T1 should have a h1: 11 k% M (for the whole k) and table T2 a h2: 13 k% M (for the whole k).

However I don't know how to connect all the features I just described.

I hope someone has the patience to give me a hand, I don't find examples of code around the Internet and this is causing me many problems. (Learning a new thing without having documentation is difficult for me)

Can anyone guide me?

```
public class JumpHashing {

    class HashEntry {

        String key;
        int value;    

        /* Constructor */
        HashEntry(String key, int value) {

            this.key = key;
            this.value = value;        
        }
    }

    class HashTable {

        private int TABLE_SIZE; //dimensions of the table
        private int size;   //number of key-value pairs 
        private HashEntry[] table;
        private int primeSize;

    /* Constructor */
    public HashTable(int ts) {

        size = 0;
        TABLE_SIZE = ts;

        table = new HashEntry[TABLE_SIZE];

        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            table[i] = null;

        primeSize = getPrime();       
    }

    /* Function to get prime number less than table size for myhash2 function */
    public int getPrime() {
        for (int i = TABLE_SIZE - 1; i >= 1; i--)
        {
            int fact = 0;
            for (int j = 2; j <= (int) Math.sqrt(i); j++)
                if (i % j == 0)
                    fact++;
            if (fact == 0)
                return i;
        }
        /* Return a prime number */
        return 3;
    }


    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return size == 0;
    }

    /* Function to clear hash table */
    public void makeEmpty() {
        size = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++)
            table[i] = null;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. This question is too open-ended for us. Try breaking it down into the most pressing single issue first, and ask for help with that. Once that is answered, open another question for the next issue, etc.

Comment: my question is all about how to set the insertion method. I think it is a simple method that receives as a parameter the key and the value to be inserted and with a series of cycles checks where to insert it. Here I don't know how to set these cycles. I don't know how to rephrase the question

Comment: > (learning a new thing without having documentation is difficult for me); then you should quit trying to be a professional programmer immediately because you will be miserable in every company. 95% of the job is figuring what other devs did years ago.

Comment: Yes, but this 95% you are referring to is already widely documented, I signed up on stackoverflow to face new problems, and not having a team or any other people to deal with, I thought I would find it here (free XD). if you want to close the question, close it, however, in my opinion it does not deserve it ... it just deserves some reasoning and comparison, not being an evergreen.

Comment: Dunno who voted you down, I voted you up. My 95% comment was just a heads up, in case you were still a student. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, you should clarify what hashtable algo you aim for.
Chained hashtable or open-addressing hashtable?

Assuming chained hashmap, it's weird what you are trying to do, and ultimately it only expresses 2 chains scatterred in 2 slots at same position. I can't see any reason to do that because doing a lookup will not be particularly any faster when examining both chains.

Assuming open addressing hashtable: it looks to me as if you simply had 2 cells instead of 1, per slot position; essentially a tiny 2-entries fixed length chain before you must hop to the next slot with whichever probe you use. So it's really a HashEntry[N][2].

Comment: exact is an open address, and yes it is essentially a HashEntry [N] [2]. What I'm trying to do is have arrays calculate different insertion indices.